# Ember service is lost on reload

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Ember.Service as a long-lived ember object cause I need it to be available in different parts of my application.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
    user:null,
    updateActiveUser(user){
        this.set('user',user);
    },
    getActiveUser(){
        const user=this.get('user');
        if(user){
            return user;
        }else{
            return null;
        }   
    }
});
```

On my component I'm asking for this user in this way:
import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
activeUser:Ember.inject.service('active-user'),
list: [],
selectedUser:null,
didReceiveAttrs() {
    this._super();
    this.set('list',this.get('model'));
    const active=this.get('activeUser').getActiveUser();
    if(active){
        this.set('selectedUser',active);
    }else{
        this.set('selectedUser',this.get('model').objectAt(0));
    }
},
actions:{
    selectUser(user){
        this.set('selectedUser',user);
        this.get('activeUser').updateActiveUser(user);

    }
}
});
```

My issue is that after I select a user and then I reload the page is not saving the last user selected and its showing the default user.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled about what you think a page reload does. It reloads the entire page from scratch, including all HTML, JS, and everything else, just as if you had closed that tab and opened the same URL in another tab.

Comment: You are right @torazaburo I forgot the local storage importance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(edited after the question has changed a bit)

You are trying to get the app state to persist on the client's browser, even after a page refresh.

I think you should look into using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

In your service do something like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  user: null,

  updateActiveUser(user){
    this.set('user', user);
    // persist the user's browser so it can be retrieved on reload
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
  },

  getActiveUser(){
    var user = this.get('user');
    if (user) {
      return user;
    } else {
      // try to get the user from localStorage
      var foundUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.user);
      if (foundUser) {
        this.set('user', foundUser);
        return foundUser;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }   
  }
});
```

Lastly, why are you using `const`? That is meant to be used if you are never going to change the variable. But it looks like the user is changed regularly. ES6 is supposed to throw an exception if you change a variable marked as **const**. [const - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Comment: Sorry, to post the question I changed the name variables, but right know it is working fine until I reload the page. That means that when I change the selected user it works well, even if I transition to other pages, but when I reload the page the selected user gets lost and give the default this.set('selectedUser',this.get('model').objectAt(0));

Comment: when you reload the page the entire application state is lost if it isn't saved to the database... so that's expected behavior. You could look at using localStorage to save it to the user's browser.

Comment: @PaulOliver Great answer, just a detail: Your localstorage param-names do no match `user` in set vs `activeUser` in get.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You're not assigning the user but an undefined variable in your code

```
updateActiveUser(user){
  this.set('user',kid); 
}
```

Should be `this.set('user', user);`

**UPDATE**

The issue is that an Ember Service does not live through page reloads because all the JS gets thrown away and reloaded (your app included).

You can store the data from your service in the browsers local storage or something similar.